# Write into android/data on Android 12 using ADB?

Tags: adb, permissions, android-12

With the addition of scoped storage in Android 11/12 I no longer have access to certain application directories within android/data.
I would like to write into this directory but since I have no permissions, I cannot do it locally using a file manager (I have tried multiple file explorers including x-plore and marc files, none of them work)

I was wondering if then there is some way to bypass this limitation using ADB?
Or any other way? Without Using Root, I am on the American S22 Ultra so there is currently no bootloader unlock/root.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Via adb it is no problem to read or write files within `/storage/emulated/0/Android`. Just connect your phone to a PC and use adb.

Comment: Will adb allow me to have write access on those directories that are read only though? Since I do not have root but this is in the home directory? Basically I am asking if this can bypass the scoped storage limit the developer has put on the android/data directory of the application within my internal storage.

Comment: adb can not be used for bypass the scoped storage limit because by default adb is not available from within an app. Note that is site is for Android users not developers. If you are asking because of app development you are wrong here. Development question belong to stackoverflow.com.